# Send SagePay "DeliveryFirstnames" and "DeliverySurname"

Tags: opayo

I have recently integrated SagePay and I need help sending over some extra variables such as the DeliveryFirstname and DeliverySurname...

I am sending everything else i.e. Delivery Address Line 1, Address Line 2, Town and Postcode however, Delivery First and Last Name does not show up when I am redirected to the Sage Pay website even though I am sending through the data? Why would this be?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9FMY.png

Comment: There is no issue with the code. I am pulling and storing the correct information as the screenshot shows. The only issue is, why isn't there a field at SagePay's end for Delivery First and Surname? I can evidently get the information through to SagePay hence the Delivery Address details. Do you have any idea how I get SagePay to show a First and Surname field in order for me to post into it?

Comment: No problem Toni, hope you can shed some light on this issue!

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You could try modifying the template (card_confirmation.xslt).

I tried it using the Custom Templates download and managed to get it to show - had to edit the cardconfirmation.xml and i18n files too.

Not sure if it would work in live, though - you'll have to give that a try!